# Register Matplotlib Colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I think this should work:

```
cm = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('phases', ['g', 'y', 'c', 'm', 'b', 'r']
plt.register_cmap('phases', cm)
```

But when I type:

```
plt.cmap.phases
```

I get an attribute error. So clearly my cmap isn't being registered as I thought. But it's not clear why.

Ben

Answer (score 5):

Your colormap gets registered. `plt.cm` only contains the **built-in** colormaps, not the registered ones.

To get the colormap use `plt.cm.get_cmap('phases')`.
To set the colormap as default use `plt.set_cmap('phases')`.
To get all built-in and registered colormaps use `plt.colormaps()`.
To get only registered (not built-in) colormaps use `[cm  for cm in plt.colormaps() if cm not in dir(plt.cm)]`.